# merge two .csv files into one file

Tags: powershell

I have two .csv files that I want to combine into one.
FileA has headers of DisplayName and Email
FileB has header of Owners. I have not been able to merge the two as one. Any help is appreciated.

The new file needs to have the headers as:

DisplayName      Email                                                 Owners

AccountA                      AccountA@company.com                    John.doe@company.com

Comment: What criteria are you planning to use to merge them?  Since they don't have any columns in common, there must be more to the story.

Comment: I'm pulling information from two different sources for the two files, but they are in the exact same order. So I just need to merge the two files as they sit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one way of doing it:

```
$filea = import-csv filea.csv
$fileb = import-csv fileb.csv

for($i=0;$i -lt $filea.count;$i++){
    $filea[$i] | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Owners -Value $fileb[$i].Owners
}

$filea | export-csv combined.csv -notype
```

Comment: It won't work if the result of $filea and $fileb is a scalar. It would be safer to cast it to array first.